# Archive workflow

Tags: workflow-activity

I created a workflow to archive items from list 1 to be moved to list 2 2x a day. (were currently using this to hold ticket request) and when this flow runs it says its successful, but the items aren't being moved over. The "error" is that the second half of my flow isn't being performed because my condition hasn't been met. (Condition: IF state value is equal to Closed) create item in list 2 and delete item from list

And I figured well its most likely because my 1st action after reoccurring was "get items" so my filter query doesn't have any dynamic content to pull from and that's why my flow isn't working properly.

So, my question is what the 1st step should be after recurrence to ensure my entire workflow runs.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have just created a test flow that is pretty much the same design as yours and it appears to be working how you would like it to. My environment seems to be using the new interface, so perhaps the old version of power automate doesn't work the same? However, one way you could confirm your theory that the issue is related to it not picking up the dynamic content would be to add a "Get item" step inside your "Apply to each" but above your condition step. That way you'd definitely get access to your dynamic content.

Comment: Are you unable to get the items using get items action? If you only want the items with "Closed" state, you should add that condition directly in get item action filters. Also, if there more than 100 items, you can mention 5000 as top count. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap can you show me what this looks like I'm not sure what you mean.